# Using loop cuts to smooth out a mesh

Tags: modeling

I was wondering if it is better or not to use loop cuts on a mesh when they are not really necessary to the shape of the mesh while using a subsurf modifier to make the spaces between each vertex approximately even, and to make the model smoother.

Here is an example: on this sword I'm modelling, there is quite a big gap on the blade without loop cuts because I don't need them for the shape of the blade.

[image: 1]

Should I use those loop cuts to make the model cleaner or can I leave it as it is?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it's a game model then no, if it's a highpoly one then yes.

Comment: You didn't need to delete your other question. You could just edit it to remove the parts that have been asked here, leaving the parts about modelling the tip.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this forum, won't do it anymore.

Comment: You can increase the crease (in N panel to ) at the edge where you want the model to be tighter .

Comment: Yes, I know that but thanks a lot for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

Don't add polygons for the sake of having more polygons, you are looking for a special shape. So would do better having a really simple shape to start with, bevel the edges that you want to be sharp and then apply a subsurface modifier. Add loopcuts afterwards if you need more details.

[image]